# Lets Encrypt expired SSL certificate amazon lightsail removal

Tags: ssl-certificate, amazon-lightsail

My SSL from Let's Encrypt has been expired. Rather than using the Lets Encrypt I want to use the on from Amazon it self. There are two questions:

1) How to remove the existing expired certificate.
2) How to install from Amazon.

Checked the various forums which say install Let's Encrypt. But not, how to remove expired one.

Any one, Help?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using apache on linux.

1) 
    certbot delete

will help you to delete the let's encrypt cert.  [Ref](https://medium.com/gatemill/correct-way-to-delete-a-certbot-ssl-certificate-e8ee123e6e01)

2)

Update cert file paths from default-ssl.conf [or whatever the file if you manually setup] inside /etc/apache2/sites-available/ with the one you bought from amazon.

Comment: How did you installed the lets encrypt in your system? Using certbot?

Comment: Yes using https://metablogue.com/enable-lets-encrypt-ssl-aws-lightsail but now is not working I get Command not found.